# How to reference a class property using the value of another class' property

Tags: php

I know I can reference a class' property using a variable as follows:

```
$field_name = 'first_name';
$myobject->$field_name // references $myobject->first_name
```

Is there a way I can reference a class property using another class' property?  For example,

```
$myobject->{$model->field_name} // Does not work
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, this will: `$field = $model->field_name; $myobject->$field;`.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a one-liner.

Comment: Your format looks correct to me.

Comment: Just make sure `$model->field_name` evaluates to a non-empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar = 'baz';
}

class Bar {
    private $baz = 'Hello, World!';

    public function __construct() {
        $foo = new Foo;
        echo $this->{$foo->bar};
    }
}

new Bar;
```

It [prints](http://codepad.org/fMImu0Dc):

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Ok, so I did have it right.  Never mind then.  Thanks for checking into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$field_name = $model->field_name
$myobject->$fieldname
```